# How can I perform a polymorphic clone with templated unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance

I have a simple class hierarchy like this:

```
struct Base 
{  
    virtual void x() = 0; 
};
struct Derived : public Base
{
    void x() override {}
};
```

And a wrapper class that basically contains a smart pointer and has the ability to create a copy out of it:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> data;

    void set(std::unique_ptr<T> d)
    {
        data = std::move(d);
    }

    std::unique_ptr<T> clone()
    {
        return std::make_unique<T>(*data.get());
    }
};
```

Now, suppose I'm using the wrapper class like this:

```
Wrapper<Base> wrapper;
wrapper.set(std::make_unique<Derived>());

std::unique_ptr<Derived> d = wrapper.clone(); // <---- Error!
```

The last line triggers an error: the `clone()` method is trying to call `new` on an abstract class (which is `Base`). It makes sense, so my current solution is to "help" the compiler by passing the right class I want to clone in the `Wrapper::clone()` method, like so:

```
template<typename C=T>
std::unique_ptr<C> clone()
{
    return std::make_unique<C>(*static_cast<C*>(data.get()));
}
```

Usage:

```
std::unique_ptr<Derived> d = wrapper.clone<Derived>();
```

It works, but is this is the right way to do it, especially in a modern C++ scenario?

Comment: Better ask such questions at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) if there's no specific problem to solve with your already working code.

Comment: Why not using shared pointers?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I fear this code might work by accident :)

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto unfortunately I can't use shared pointers on the actual code for several reasons (multithreading issues, mostly)

Comment: You can add a virtual `clone()` method to `Base` and implement it in `Derived`. P.S. nitpicking, `Base` needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: Even `base.clone()`won't return static type `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` (but dynamic type can be `Derived` instead of `Base`).

Comment: If your concern is with correctness rather than style, you could explicitly phrase your question as asking about standards compliance.